# Cross object dependant picklist validation

Tags: validation, picklist

Hi i am having a two picklist in salesforce  one is on account object and one is on contact object. If i am having a1,a2,a3 as picklist values in both.

if i select a value in contact is a1 and in contact's account is a2 then it must show an error

Comment: Have a validation rule on your account field. btw, if it's mandatory to select same value, why you maintaining it in both objects?

Comment: are these multiselect picklists?

Comment: If the account is leading, why not show the value on the contact through a formula field ?

Comment: Jason, we'r trying to close that other one as duplicate, this is the older question posted.

Answer (score 0):

If those are not multi-select picklist fields, try below formular

```
TEXT( Owner.Contact.Contact_PickList__c ) <> TEXT( Account_PickList__c )
```

I'm assuming that you are adding this validation rule on the `Account` object.