# Validation using two Picklist Fields in 2 objects

Tags: validation, picklist

I'm trying to create a validation rule formula in Salesforce, that uses two picklist fields which have the same values : p1, p2, p3.

One of the picklists is on the account object and the other one on the contact object.

If the selected value on the contact record is `p1` and on the contact's account record is `p2` then I would like to throw an error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am Trying for a validation rule Account.selectlist__c <> selectlist__c  . But i am getting an error "Error: Field selectlist__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions."

Comment: [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30518/what-do-i-need-to-select-workflow-trigger-or-coding) also refer to the same question is it?

Comment: are these multi-select picklists?

Comment: With a validation rule, you can only check this when the Contact is saved, not the Account.

Comment: To clarify, where is the validation rule?  If it's on the Contact, then are you basically saying "Set the Contact picklist value to the value on the Account"?  If so, then this would be better suited as a formula or field update since it would improve data collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functions: ISPICKLIST and TEXT

> **ISPICKLIST**
>
> Determines if the value of a picklist field is equal to a text literal you specify.
>
> **Text**
>
> Converts a percent, number, date, date/time, or currency type field into text anywhere formulas are used. Also, converts ***picklist values*** to text in approval rules, approval step rules, workflow rules, escalation rules, assignment rules, auto-response rules, validation rules, formula fields, field updates, and custom buttons and links.
>
> [Docu](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm&language=en_US)

**Validation rule**

```
ISPICKVAL(Account.selectlist__c, Text(selectlist__c))
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to create a validation rule on the account object with error condition formula like below if test_*c is the common picklist field.
 test*_c  <> Owner.Contact.test__c

Answer (score -1):

If those are not multi-select picklist fields, try below formular

```
TEXT( Owner.Contact.Contact_PickList__c ) <> TEXT( Account_PickList__c )
```

I'm assuming that you are adding this validation rule on the `Account` object.